# Having multiple connected errors randomly with Flask - SQLALchemy - MariaDB/MySQL application

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, mariadb, flask-sqlalchemy

From time to time, we get some of these errors in our application:

```
InterfaceError

(pymysql.err.InterfaceError) (0, '')
[SQL: SELECT notification_states.id AS notification_states_id, notification_states.name AS notification_states_name 
FROM notification_states 
WHERE notification_states.name = %(name_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: {'name_1': 'new', 'param_1': 1}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/rvf5)
```

```
AttributeError

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'settimeout'
```

```
RuntimeError

reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedReader name=40>
```

```
PendingRollbackError

Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back.  Please rollback() fully before proceeding (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/8s2b)
```

They appear on different reqests, quite randomly.

Also, possibly connected, in db logs we have `Aborted connections (Got an error reading communication packetes)` A LOT (many times per minute).

Stack:

- Flask 2.2.3
- Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.0.3
- SQLAlchemy 2.0.7
- pymysql 1.0.3
- gunicorn + gevent
- MariaDB - 10.5.18-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 Debian 11
- Debian - 5.10.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.162-1 (2023-01-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux

SQLAlchemy setting:

```py
db = SQLAlchemy(
    session_options={"autoflush": False},
    metadata=MetaData(naming_convention=convention),
)
```

Configuration:

```
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {"pool_pre_ping": True, "pool_recycle": 600}
SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW = -1
```

We need some pointers, questions or anything to help us find a root cause of this issue.
We tried googling all the errors, read multiple SO questions, GH issues, but nothing helped us to solve this.

Thank you for any response!

Updates:
We tried multiple things meantime, nothing helped much:

- We stopped using connection pooling (enabling NullPool). This made `Aborted connections` db errors stop, but didn't help with the main issue.
- We stopped using web-sockets. This didn't change anything.